# Custom NavigationBar in UINavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4.5

I have a UITableViewController in a UINavigationcontroller and i want to add a custom navigation bar in it. if I do this in the tableView class, it scrolls along with the table an that's not what I want. if I do this in the NavigationController class, it does not appear.

I have created a UINavigatioBar in my NavigationController NIB File, and connected it as an IBOutlet to my Navigationcontroller.h. in my NavigationController.m I have:

`productsNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1048, 88)];
 [productsNavigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
 [self.view addSubview:productsNavigationBar];`

who knows what to do to make my Bar appear?

Comment: if you are using it only with UITableViewController then add your content in Header of UITableView it will solve your problem

Comment: hi @Joris Dijkstra, remember me?

Comment: My tableView cells are not just cells with static content, they are containing a number of textfields. I want to provide the user withs some tools like add/remove rows, change font etc, so I don't think only 2 leftBarButton and rightBarButton are enough.

Comment: yes @DipenPanchasara, I do remember you. you were really great help with the table/navigation problem

Comment: i have posted some code below, try this and add button in that headerview as per your requirement, it may solve your problem..!

Answer (score 0):

Implement this DataSource method in your tableViewController and add what ever you want as Navigation Bar in Header of UITableView

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    return headerView;
}
```

To change the height of Header IMplement this method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100.0f;
}
```

Comment: Your code does add a section header, but the height does not seem to be customizable. when I change "30" to "100", the height does not change. I need to customize the NavigationBar.

Comment: I actually can add a custom UINavigationBar, but only in my tableview. when I do that, it scrolls up with the tableView (I used the code in my question). do you know a way I can add such a custom bar in the Navigationcontroller, to prevent it from scrolling with the tableView?

Comment: Thank you! I was already searching for such a method. Let me try to add a custom background Image and some buttons to it.

Comment: so it is not possible to add a custom navigation bar in NavigationController?

Comment: its not custom navigation bar , but its just a header view in UITableView

Comment: yes this is, i know. But originally I tried to add a custom navigation bar. because you gave me a method for a section header, i thought it it not possible to do that?

Comment: it actually gave me a large customizable bar on top of my table, let me check if i can add buttons etc, that I know if it works

Comment: @JorisDijkstra whats the insight?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27420/discussion-between-joris-dijkstra-and-dipen-panchasara)